# Should an off-topic question with an accepted answer be placed on-hold?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question which I had accepted an answer to: [How to split filenames for their first word in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143395/how-to-split-filenames-for-their-first-word-in-python)

Now, I understand why PolyGeo placed it 'on-hold' as it is pretty much a software-oriented question, my apologies for that. But since the question has been answered, is there much point in it being flagged?

One could argue that if a question like "*What's the best cooking oil to fry marshmallows in?*" was asked and accepted an answer on GIS:SE, then I completely understand why that would be flagged and migrated. But since my question does involve using and processing shapefiles which are GIS-based, I am just wondering if there are any benefits in flagging this and other questions of a similar ilk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we don't flag them then the next person who asks a software question points to it as precedent. I closed a similar java question yesterday - just because your file is a shapefile doesn't make it geographic.